# Load clientId and clientSecret from database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

In my application(currently it supports google and Facebook login), clientId and clientSecret store in the application.properties file. Now I want to store those details in the database (they need to change those values dynamically). How can I do it? Is it bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Security reads the OAuth client information from a `ClientRegistrationRepository` object. By default, it's in memory (SpringBoot autoconfigures an `InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository` bean) and populated with the data you put in `application.properties`. To fetch it from a database, you can implement the `ClientRegistrationRepository` interface which has only one method: `ClientRegistration findByRegistrationId(String registrationId)`. In your implementation, you would use the `registrationId` parameter to fetch the details from a database and return a `ClientRegistration` object (the `ClientRegistrations` class provides a builder for that). I recommend not saving the clientSecret in cleartext in the database. You can use one of the utilities offered by the [Spring Security Crypto](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.6/reference/html5/#crypto) module to encrypt/decrypt the value.